# sentry - after logout the session value is still alive

Tags: php, laravel, session, cartalyst-sentry

why is this happening?
What is wrong here?

I put a value into a session variable before I logout the user.
After this, I use the logout function from sentry: `Sentry::logout();`
But after logout, the value in my session variable is still alive.. why?

This is my code:

```
    Session::put('test', 1);
    // Log the user out
    Sentry::logout();
    echo(Session::get('test'));
    exit;
```

I got `1` in the output, but I'am expecting nothing ...
i thought the `Sentry::logout()` function will destroy all the session data?
This is really confusing..

EDIT:

> I got it! The cookie name in the sentry config must be the same as
>   defined in the config/session.php from laravel!

Answer (score 0):

try using:

```
// when logging out you can use: 
    Auth::logout();  // or     
    Sentry::logout(); // (or both if you are logged in with both methods )
// if you want to Remove All Items From The Session use the following function:
    Session::flush();
```